# My xquery in not using "count" properly

Tags: xml, xquery

i am trying to develop a query for a xml file where i want to count a number of `calib` made where the `$y/colheita/cod_colheita="FE23569" and $y/colheita/@ano="2018"` and i try to return the count of `return count($y/colheita/lotes/lote/calibragem/calib)`

I dont understand why i it's not returning the number of calibs.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style_macaMoimenta.xsl"?>
<moimenta xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:gnr="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/general" xmlns:clt="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/lote"
xmlns:prc="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/precario"
xmlns:clb="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/calibragem"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/ moimenta.xsd">
<produtores>
    <produtor>
        <codigo>PR001</codigo>
        <nome>Antonio Manuel</nome>
        <data_registo>2018-03-20</data_registo>
        <morada>
            <gnr:rua>Rua Antonio Manuel</gnr:rua>
            <gnr:numero>69</gnr:numero>
            <gnr:cod_postal>4569-123</gnr:cod_postal>
        </morada>
        <colheita ano="2018" qualidade="Ambrosia">
            <cod_colheita>FE23569</cod_colheita>
            <valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="0-60">
                    <prc:preco>0.10</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="60-65">
                    <prc:preco>0.13</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="65-70">
                    <prc:preco>0.17</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="DEFEITO">
                    <prc:preco>0.05</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
            </valor>
            <lotes>
                <lote>
                    <clt:n_lote>236598</clt:n_lote>
                    <clt:quantidade>2500</clt:quantidade>
                    <clt:calibragem>
                        <clb:calib valor="0-60">
                            <clb:quantidade>1000</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="60-65">
                            <clb:quantidade>1300</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="DEFEITO">
                            <clb:quantidade>200</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                    </clt:calibragem>
                </lote>
            </lotes>
        </colheita>
    </produtor>
</produtores>
```

Xquery

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/";

for $y in /moimenta/produtores/produtor
where $y/colheita/cod_colheita="FE23569" and 
$y/colheita/@ano="2018"
return count($y/colheita/lotes/lote/calibragem/calib)
```

I just need to do this query with two determinants, the `cod_colheita="FE23569"` and `$y/colheita/@ano="2018"` and i need it to return the number of `calib` done inside that `colheita/lotes/lote`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to count

```
count(
  (for $y in /moimenta/produtores/produtor
   where $y/colheita/cod_colheita="FE23569" 
   and $y/colheita/@ano="2018"
   return $y)/colheita/lotes/lote/calibragem/calib
)
```

or perhaps shorter

```
count(/moimenta/produtores/produtor/colheita[cod_colheita="FE23569" and @ano="2018"]/lotes/lote/calibragem/calib)
```

This should work if all elements were in the same default namespace but as two other namespaces are involved you need to more namespace declarations and use the prefixes:

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/";

declare namespace clt = "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/lote";
declare namespace clb = "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/calibragem";

count(/moimenta/produtores/produtor/colheita[cod_colheita="FE23569" and @ano="2018"]/lotes/lote/clt:calibragem/clb:calib)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y7

The namespace fix also works for your original attempt once the `count` call is done for the right expression:

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/";

declare namespace clt = "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/lote";
declare namespace clb = "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/calibragem";

count(
  (for $y in /moimenta/produtores/produtor
   where $y/colheita/cod_colheita="FE23569" 
   and $y/colheita/@ano="2018"
   return $y)/colheita/lotes/lote/clt:calibragem/clb:calib
)
```

That is difficult to read however, it might be clearer, if you want to use a `for` expression, to use e.g.

```
let $colheitas := 
   for $y in /moimenta/produtores/produtor/colheita
   where $y/cod_colheita="FE23569" 
   and $y/@ano="2018"
   return $y
return count($colheitas/lotes/lote/clt:calibragem/clb:calib)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y7/1

Comment: it shouldn't have another for cicle because it keeps giving me 0. and i am expecting to be 3

Comment: Thank you very much, there's a very important question that i would like to know the answer. Can i use an if statement in a query?

Comment: Why don't you bookmark the XQuery spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/ and start searching there if question arise? If you are looking for "statements" in a declarative language you are probably on the wrong track from the beginning, but there is a conditional expression https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-conditionals.